# Can I change virtual machine auto shut down time after azure virtual machine created using Rest Api?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-web-app-service, azure-rest-api

This Api on this URL can be helpfull ?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/dtl/virtualmachineschedules/get

Please Help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the API you provided is for the VM in Azure DevTest Labs, if you want to change the auto shut downtime for a normal azure VM, use the one below.

To acquire an access token, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#acquire-an-access-token).

Request URL:

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/microsoft.devtestlab/schedules/shutdown-computevm-<VMname>?api-version=2018-09-15
```

Request header:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0exxxxx6dyJ9
```

Request body(`1900` means `19:00` i.e. `7:00:00 PM`):

```
{
  "properties": {
    "taskType": "ComputeVmShutdownTask",
    "timeZoneId": "China Standard Time",
    "dailyRecurrence": {
      "time": "1900"
    },
    "targetResourceId": "/subscriptions/<subscription-id>/resourceGroups/<resource-group-name>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/<VMname>",
    "status": "Enabled",
    "notificationSettings": {
      "timeInMinutes": 30,
      "status": "Disabled"
    }
  },
  "location": "eastus"
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Joy !  This Works for my compute Vms

Comment: Hi Joy I have one more question, before your response I also tried to schedule auto shutdown on vm using  runbooks under automation account where I can also have auto start feature but I stuck in one thing that is if I have runbook under Automation Account and in that runbook I want to use link to schedule settings using any Rest Api (Automation Account => runbbooks => link to schedule) ?                              Currently azure have Any rest api to use link to schedule settings under runbbooks ?

Comment: @SoumyaMishra If I understand you correctly, you want to add a schedule to the runbook, if so, you could use this api:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/jobschedule/create

Comment: I already tried for this api but how to get jobScheduleId for this api ?  
and jobSchduleId also can get from this api try to put but getting error                   {
    "code": "NotFound",
    "message": "Job Schedule not found."
}                                                              https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxxx-xxx-xx-xxx-xxxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/xxx/jobs?api-version=2015-10-31

Comment: Now I am getting -                                                                                                      {
    "code": "NotFound",
    "message": "Runbook not found."
}

Comment: @SoumyaMishra `Job Schedule` is not `Job`, just try the body `{
  "properties": {
    "schedule": {
      "name": "<schedule-name>"
    },
    "runbook": {
      "name": "<runbook-name>"
    },
    "parameters": {}
  }
}` in this api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/jobschedule/create , just generate a GUID for `jobScheduleId`.

Comment: management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/TestRunbook2/jobSchedules/4fb4db16-4aa7-4cbf-be40-2030faaab78b?api-version=2015-10-31                                                       
Json Body :-
{ "properties": 
  { 
 "schedule": 
 { 
  "name": "ForStartVM11" 
  
 },
  "runbook": 
  { 
   "name": "TestRunbook2" 
  },
  "parameters": {} 
 
  } 
}    getting same error as above Runbook not found.

Comment: GUID - 4fb4db16-4aa7-4cbf-be40-2030faaab78b which is mentioned generated online

Comment: @SoumyaMishra The `automationAccountName` is not the `runbook-name`, I notice you use the same value for them.

Comment: @SoumyaMishra check this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6aoi.png

Comment: Thank You so much Joy !!! yes it was my mistake,I passed wrong parameters in json, now it's working